# Every time I run a statistical test, my n-value is doubled

Tags: repeated-measures, spss, small-sample, friedman-test

I just finished collecting data for a small study with a within-subject design looking at caching behaviour and how it can be affected by a bird's surroundings. My study had three experimental conditions and each bird (n = 5) participated in each condition twice. I was planning on running a Friedman ANOVA because my data is non-parametric and doesn't meet the assumptions for a repeated measures ANOVA.

The first image is a screenshot of my SPSS data. It's extremely simplified because I took out any extraneous data. The values shown are the number of caches made  by each bird (listed on the rows) in each condition (listed on the columns).
[image: SPSS data editor view]

Here is where I run into an issue: whenever I try to run a Friedman ANOVA, the output keeps showing a doubled n-value (for example: n=10 instead of n=5).
[image: SPSS Output for Friedman ANOVA]

I think I understand why it is doing this, it's just that I don't know what to do about it. I done some research online and the main two answers I've been able to find (at least without going into a bunch of detail about my study like I am now) are either: a) take the average of any individuals that were tested more than once or b) run the test as usual and substitute out the incorrect n-value for your correct sample size. I really have no idea if either of those are right.

The other possibility I have been thinking is that I might have my data set up incorrectly or that there could be a setting or function on SPSS that might help me.

I'm open to any help or suggestions and I hope that I helped explain my question/dilemma a little more this time around. Please let me know if anything else isn't clear and I will gladly add more explanation.

Comment: Your question really is about SPSS.  First you need to get SPSS under your control.  Afterwards there might not be anything left to do.  It would be nice to keep this question open, but it's hard to see how an objective answer could be offered without knowing the details of this "analysis" you refer to.  Please feel free to edit your post to clarify this: that will prompt users to reopen it.

Comment: I was wondering if this question could possibly be reopened? I've made significant changes to the question itself and completely rewrote it so that it would be easier for users to understand it. Also, as suggested, I added details of the analysis I am referring to in the question (as well as SPSS screen shots). Thank you for you time.